# How to get all distinct rows based on a particular column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

It seems due to changes in MySQL 5.7 or higher, the SQL mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default so the good old code I had which looked like the following:

```
Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

now throws the error...

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
```

I tried updating my code in various ways to try and make it work but no luck.

This is what I currently have:

```
Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%')
    ->selectRaw('name, ANY_VALUE(id), ANY_VALUE(col_a), ANY_VALUE(col_b), ANY_VALUE(col_c), ANY_VALUE(col_d)')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```

This doesn't throw any errors but the column data is missing.

I've also tried:

```
Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Which does not return distinct rows based on 'name'. It just returns everything.

How can I do this in Laravel Eloquent or raw MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried `->distinct()->get();`

Comment: I've looked into distinct() too. It only returns one row though. I'm trying to get multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

The [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby) method groups the collection's items by a given key. You should get a collection first:

```
Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('name');
```

Comment: This is still returning all results but in groups. I only want distinct rows based on name. It would be best if the query itself can handle everything. This requires hitting the database and also manipulating the query result afterwards so it's slower too.

Comment: @rotaercz For that try: `Table::select('name')->groupBy('name')->get();`

Comment: That wouldn't work because I need the full row with all it's columns. The columns may or may not have unique values.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/database.php` file change `'strict' => true,` to `'strict' => false,`  and try

```
Table::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%')
->groupBy('name')
->get();
```

I am not sure if you are looking for this.

Comment: That would probably work but I'd like to keep it strict and get it to work.